# Can NFS server limit the amount of disk space by client IP address

Tags: nfs, quota

I have already read this question :
[Can NFS server limit the amount of disk space that the NFS client can use?](https://serverfault.com/questions/644749/can-nfs-server-limit-the-amount-of-disk-space-that-the-nfs-client-can-use)

But I still can't find the tutorials about how to do that.

My scenery is NFS Server（192.168.1.100）have 1000GB storage space，and there are 10 NFS clients (192.168.1.1～192.168.1.10)，each with many users. I want to limit each client to only use 50GB (no matter who uses the space, even if John uses all of 50GB), so the 10 clients up to use 500GB disk space.

Is there anyway to realize the storage limits by Client IP address?

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: shortly said by ip no, by user or group yes, but as you did not telling any informations our glassball is telling me that's it ;)

Comment: The NFS is only a transport to access the **remote file system**, thus it any usage limits can be applied only on the file system itself. If you don't care about diggerent users per host, then you can map all users from a particular host to a single uid/gid, and then apply quota based solution.

Comment: How can I map all users from a particular host to a single uid/gid